# How to get the character value of a keyCode

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've a script which captures keyCode(eg: 67, 78..) on keyup
how to get the character of that keyCode (including shift/capslock function)


Like 89 for 'y'
is there are any way using jquery/javascript?

Comment: @TarunPai That comment doesn't help OP. You could have flagged the question with a duplicate question link if available or a link which would help OP.

Comment: Not an answer, and I don't have time to post one, but [this page on keycodes and keyboard events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) may be useful.

Comment: if u dont have the solution please don vote or comment @Tarun

Comment: There are rules here on SO on the kind of questions you should as and should NOT ask, read up here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I presume you mean `'y'` -> `121`, not `89`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

use **[String.fromCharCode()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromCharCode.asp)**:

```
 String.fromCharCode(window.event.keyCode);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VLZGk/358/)**

**Fix for firefox:**

```
$("#txtInput").keypress(
        function (e) {
             evt = e || window.event;
             var keyPressed = evt.which || evt.keyCode
             console.log(String.fromCharCode(keyPressed));
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VLZGk/360/)**

Comment: Keycodes aren't what `fromCharCode` uses. Keycodes are...[keycodes](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html). `fromCharCode` accepts Unicode code points (well, the first 65,536 of them; I hear ES6 will expand that).

Comment: ITS WORKING BUT ITS ONLY GIVING UPPERCASE CHARS AND not correctly giving non english characters (eg: '.],)... any fix?

Comment: Using `window.event.keyCode` doesn't change anything, and breaks Firefox.

Comment: @Ario:updated now. check it

Comment: This answer is still incorrect. Paste this code into the console: `document.onkeyup = function () { console.log(String.fromCharCode(window.event.keyCode)); };`, then press the `\`` key on your keyboard. Is that the same character? This also throws a TypeError in Firefox.

Comment: @OneKitten:thanks updated the fix for firefox now...

Comment: @onekitten ` is the same character... and Millind's demo is working perfectly in all browsers... including IE

Comment: @Ario ??? http://i.stack.imgur.com/WMToK.png